# Javascript functional scoping, how to get around it?

Tags: javascript, variables, scoping

So basically I'm trying to create an alternative to the `setTimeout` function because it doesn't work for my purposes.

```
addInterval(func, wait_time){
    this.intervals.push(func);
    this.interval_waits.push(wait_time);
    this.updateInterval(this.interval_waits.length - 1);
}
updateInterval(index){
    console.log(index);
    function callTimeout(index, timeC){
        let i = index;
        let t = timeC;
        timeC.startTimeout(function(){  
            console.log(i);
            t.intervals[i](t.interval_depends[i]);
            t.updateInterval(i);
        }, t.interval_waits[i]);
    }
    let a = index;
    callTimeout(a, this);
}
```

When `this.updateInterval` is called, it sends the values `0-6` to `updateInterval` one at a time, this function calls an inner function called `callTimeout` that starts another function (too long to include) but basically when `callTimeout` executes the function that is passed along, it only uses the final value (6) from `updateInterval`. I cannot get around using a parameter for `updateInterval` because it is recalled in the function passed through `startTimeout()`, and I need it to retain the same value it was initially called with, however that value is the problem in question.

I'm not sure if I worded this well this is my first ever question tell me if I need to change anything please.

I've tried using `this` instead of `var` in a plethora of places.

Comment: Not certain what the issue is. Have you tried using `.bind()` or `.call()` to set `this` at the  specific function and pass parameters?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, but waiting in a cpu loop instead of using `setTimeout` or `setInterval` is almost never seen in JavaScript and lends to poor user experiences because updating the screen, downloading stuff, etc., normally happens in a hidden event loop when your code isn't running.

Comment: As a helpful hint for writing good questions, a good question is sufficiently self-contained that it could run by itself and then visitors can fiddle with it and help you debug it.  This question instead contains a disconnect between the paragraph "When..." and the code as there is no sending of the specific values 0-6. Also `startTimeout` and `callTimeout` are not defined in the supplied code.

Comment: Finally, it seems like the code is trying to do some dependency management with events.  That is, when a certain event or interval happens, it is supposed to run the things that are associated with that interval.  At least I assume  `t.interval_depends[i]` is there to manage something like that.   A sane way to manage events (with information that can change) and dependencies that need to run when those events occur is an `EventEmitter`.  [EventEmitter](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter) is built into nodejs and there are libraries for the browser.